# CKEDITOR.inline first load

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ckeditor, contenteditable

CKEDITOR is giving me some hard time with the first load, i use:

```
CKEDITOR.inline
```

1. on the first load it takes about 2 seconds to load, on these two seconds if the user edit the div's content, when the CKEDITOR finally loads it restores it to before the edit :\ is there a way to fix it or maybe read-only the text untill the CKEDITOR loads? Right now i use opacity0 untill ckeditor is ready but it is a cheap hack and doesnt look good.
2. on the first load, the toolbar starts at the most left side of the screen, which on the other loads doesnt happen when it appears perfectly above the div being eddited.

I cant figure out how on the ckeditor inline demo they did it perfectly.

Comment: @Reinmar Please, i've seen so many ask for this and no answares.

Comment: So many? This is the first time that I see someone with this problem.

Comment: You have a thought on how to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you are having performance issues outside CKEditor to be honest. I'd try profiling the site and monitoring the web traffic used to see if that is slowing the CKE startup time. But like you said, surely you could do a `readonly` attribute for the text and then remove it during `CKEDITOR.on('instancecreated' ,...)` or some other convenient time.

Comment: there is nothing todo with server performance! if you'r on the road and have low internet connection it can take 10 seconds to load the CKEditor! all i'm asking is how to pre-load it.

Comment: Someone? Please help!

Comment: I am also seeing this issue where on first page load an initial click on a line to edit (convert to ckeditor inline) it takes longer to initialise the first editor instance.  Other instances create quickly.  Unfortunately due to this slowness if the user starts typing before the editor of fully configured then unpredictable results can happen.  WHEN I find the solution I will share.

Comment: Wow 5.5 years later and someone comments he still encounters it.. lol shame on you CKEditor..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little too vague to really grasp any single underlying question. I would post this as a comment, but it is too long, so I'll just go ahead and add as answer. What do you mean by preloading the editor? Do you want to stop the user from editing content or do you want to load the editor before loading the HTML body content? Both are basically the same as "use opacity0 until ckeditor is ready but it is a cheap hack and doesn't look good.", what is the difference?

I wasn't talking about server performance in my comment, I was talking about client performance. There are many, many things you could try

- Build a prettier fake preloader; for example mask the site with an overlay until CKE is ready
- Defer DOM creation until CKEDITOR.instanceready or whatever event is usable for you. By this I mean you can just create a pretty loading animation and get the actual editable content with JS, this will look like a preloader too
- Enable content editable only in document.ready or in some other later event, that might help
- Monitor the network, see how long CKE requests load and if that is acceptable for you
- Check that you are not using the source version of CKE
- Check that caching works as expected
- Minimize the load by removing any and all plugins you don't need

All of that is just for question number 1. As for "on the first load, the toolbar starts at the most left side of the screen, which on the other loads doesn't happen when it appears perfectly above the div being edited.", could we get a sample or how to reproduce this or a URL where this happens or even a screenshot? Based on that it is very hard to reproduce.

Comment: I'll start off by saying thank you for answaring, been waiting for a month. now the issue at hand, the site overlay idea is a good one, but it seems too heavy for a user wanting to edit the first text of line (surly will ruin the experience). what i want is the site to load 2 seconds later OR load it as soon as the site is ready, so by the time the user gets to clicking the editable content, the CK will fire right up and ready to go. any idea on how to do that?

Comment: P.S. after the first success display of CKEditor inline instance, it loads instantly on any other contentEditable in the page.

Comment: Hmm, it is a challenging issue. What if the site overlay was just a blank white page, that would give the same user experience as a 2 second longer load time, wouldn't it? This is all the options I could think of, sorry. Maby someone else will come up with a better answer!

Comment: There is a loader page for the system so it is not a blank page, .. wish there was a command to load into an invisible div